# Composer update not working to update laravel dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When I try to run composer update, I get the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: '$_' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am not sure why this happens, but I have tried updating composer itself (which runs successfully) and it does not work.  Composer usually works just fine, so I am a little bit confused.

**Added composer file:**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
        "bogardo/mailgun": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the composer json file?

Comment: At what point does the Exception get thrown?  Is there any more output?  Try deleting the `"scripts"` block from `composer.json`.  It might be an error your *your* code causing Laravel to yell at you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I seem to have solved my problem.  I need to keep the scripts because it powers my deployment.  I needed to run `composer update --no-scripts` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: what is the actual problem behind it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is located in your code.
Try to run

```
php artisan
```

if the error gets thrown also it is a problem in your code.

```
composer
```

fails also because in the

> scripts

section you run `php artisan`.

Answer (score 0):

try this command `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.